# PHP - Cleaner, More Elegant Way to Validate Content of Forms

Tags: php, forms, coding-style, submit

I am currently working on a Upload page, where users enter in values to forms then click submit. I am going to check to see if the forms have been submitted, and if submitted that they weren't empty. Here is my current code

```
function validPost()
{
    if(isset($_POST["title"]) && //if a post has been submitted
       isset($_POST["artist"]) &&
       isset($_POST["genre"]) &&
       isset($_POST["url"]) &&
       isset($_POST["user"]) ) 
    { 
        if (strlen($_POST['title']) <= 0) {
            echo 'ERROR: Please enter a title. </ br>';
            return false;
        }
        else if (strlen($_POST['artist']) <= 0) {
            echo 'ERROR: Please enter an artist. </ br>';
            return false;
        }
        else if (strlen($_POST['genre']) <= 0) {
            echo 'ERROR: Please select a genre. </ br>';
            return false;
        }
        else if (strlen($_POST['url']) <= 0) {
            echo 'ERROR: Please enter a url. </ br>';
            return false;
        }
        else if (strlen($_POST['user']) <= 0) {
            echo 'ERROR: Please enter a username to submit the song (or make one up). </ br>';
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    else //if no post was submitted
    { 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to check this? I plan on adding more checks in the future to the content submitted by these forms and I feel like this is a sloppy way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that all of the fields will be check for non-zero string lengths only:

```
$field_checks = array(
//   'fieldname' => 'errormessage'
   'title' => 'Please enter a title',
   'url' => 'Please enter a URL',
   etc...
);

$errors = array();    
foreach ($field_checks as $field => $errmsg) {       
    if (!isset($_POST[$field]) || ($_POST[$field] === '')) {
        $errors[] = $errmsg;
    }
}

if (count($errors) > 0) {
     print_r($errors); // probably want a nicer error display than this
     return false;
}
```

Comment: You need a slight tweak to check that all the fields were posted - right now if a field wasn't even posted, it will appear valid (ok, probably wouldn't happen in real world unless someone was *trying* to cheat the form, but that could be the case.

Comment: @MarcB - Thanks! Worked perfect and much cleaner now. Never seen the '===' operator before so it was good to learn about that. What is this syntax called: `$errors[] = $errmsg;` ? I've never seen it and not sure what it does so I want to look it up.

Comment: @insomnihack: `$var[] = $val` is the same as doing `array_push($var, $val)`. it's a handy syntax shortcut.

Answer (score -2):

Check into jQuery and the validate plugin

Comment: This is on the client side and can EASILY be bypassed, potentially causing a huge security concern.

Comment: Client side validation is nice, but one should always validate server side for any critical values... I think the ideal, user friendly and secure solution is to do both.

Comment: from a UI perspective, it sucks having to submit something only to find out that there was an error.